# Стрелка с изменемой точкой

Tags: javascript, html5, svg, canvas

Я пытаюсь воспроизвести эффект [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/). Когда вы рисуете стрелку, она отображает синюю точку в середине стрелки, которая позволяет создать угол между двумя линиями, и отображает две синие точки, которые позволяют вам сделать то же самое с двумя новыми линиями.

Я добавил изображение ниже, чтобы было легче понять. Интересно, как динамически кодировать эти синие точки, которые позволяют «ломать» линию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликнули между крайними точками стрелки и повернули её часть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код, что у меня получилось :

```js
var ctx = tempcanvas.getContext('2d'),
    mainctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    x1,
    y1,
    isDown = false;

ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

tempcanvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    x1 = e.clientX - rect.left;
    y1 = e.clientY - rect.top;
    isDown = true;
}
tempcanvas.onmouseup = function() {
    isDown = false;
    mainctx.drawImage(tempcanvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
tempcanvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

    if (!isDown) return;
    
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y2 = e.clientY - rect.top;
    var p0={x1,y1};
    var p1={x2,y2};


    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    drawLineWithArrowhead(p0,p1,25);

}




function drawLineWithArrowhead(p0,p1,headLength){

  
  var PI=Math.PI;
  var degreesInRadians225=225*PI/180;
  var degreesInRadians135=135*PI/180;

  
  var dx=p1.x2-p0.x1;
  var dy=p1.y2-p0.y1;
  var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

  // calc arrowhead points
  var x225=p1.x2+headLength*Math.cos(angle+degreesInRadians225);
  var y225=p1.y2+headLength*Math.sin(angle+degreesInRadians225);
  var x135=p1.x2+headLength*Math.cos(angle+degreesInRadians135);
  var y135=p1.y2+headLength*Math.sin(angle+degreesInRadians135);

  
  ctx.beginPath();
  // draw the line from p0 to p1
  ctx.moveTo(p0.x1,p0.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x2,p1.y2);
  // draw partial arrowhead at 225 degrees
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x2,p1.y2);
  ctx.lineTo(x225,y225);
  // draw partial arrowhead at 135 degrees
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x1,p1.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x135,y135);
  // stroke the line and arrowhead
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {position:absolute;left:0;top:0}
#canvas {background:#eef}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
<canvas id="tempcanvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60363651/7394871

Answer (score 6):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первым щелчком вы указываете начало стрелки, вторым кликом конец стрелки, её можно перетаскивать.

Если кликнуть между крайними точками, образуется новый узел, как шарнир, вокруг которого можно вращать часть стрелки.

Надеюсь это поможет в ответе на ваш вопрос, читайте также комментарии в коде:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const P2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x, y});
const points = [];
const lineStyle = "#000";
const nearLineStyle = "#0AF";
const lineWidth = 2;
const nearLineWidth = 3;
const pointStyle = "#000";
const nearPointStyle = "#0AF";
const pointLineWidth = 1;
const nearPointLineWidth = 2;
const arrowSize = 18;
const pointSize = 5;
const nearPointSize = 15;
const checkerSize = 256;  // удвоение
const checkerCol1 = "#CCC";
const checkerCol2 = "#EEE";
const MIN_SELECT_DIST = 20; // в пикселях;
var w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2, ch = h / 2;
var cursor = "default";
var toolTip = "";
const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, button: 0 };
const drag = {dragging: false};
requestAnimationFrame(update);

function mouseEvents(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX - ctx.bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - ctx.bounds.top - scrollY;
    if (e.type === "mousedown") { mouse.button |= 1 << (e.which - 1) }
    else if (e.type === "mouseup") { mouse.button &= ~(1 << (e.which - 1)) }
}
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
const checkerboard = (()=> {
    const s = checkerSize, s2 = s / 2;
    const c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.height = c.width = checkerSize;
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
    ctx.fillStyle = checkerCol1;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,s, s);
    ctx.fillStyle = checkerCol2;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,s2,s2);
    ctx.fillRect(s2,s2,s2,s2);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.25;
    var ss = s2;
    while(ss > 8) {
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(c, "repeat");  
        ctx.setTransform(1/8,0,0,1/8,0,0);
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,s * 8,s * 8);
        ss /= 2;
    }
    return ctx.createPattern(c, "repeat");   
})();

function nearestPointLine(points, point, minDist){   // fills nearest object with nearest point and line to point if within minDist.
    var i = 0, p1, dist;
    nearest.reset(minDist);
    const v1 = P2();
    const v2 = P2();
    const v3 = P2();
    for (const p of points) {
        v2.x = point.x - p.x;
        v2.y = point.y - p.y;
        dist = (v2.x * v2.x + v2.y * v2.y) ** 0.5;
        if(dist < nearest.point.dist) {
            nearest.point.dist = dist;
            nearest.point.p = p;
            nearest.point.idx = i;
        }           
        if (p1) {
            v1.x = p1.x - p.x;
            v1.y = p1.y - p.y;
            v2.x = point.x - p.x;
            v2.y = point.y - p.y;
            const u = (v2.x * v1.x + v2.y * v1.y) / (v1.y * v1.y + v1.x * v1.x);
           
            if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) { // ближайшая точка на отрезке
                v3.x = p.x + v1.x * u;
                v3.y = p.y + v1.y * u;
                //ctx.fillRect(v3.x, v3.y, 5, 5)
                dist = ((v3.y - point.y) ** 2 + (v3.x - point.x) ** 2) ** 0.5;
                if(dist < nearest.line.dist) {
                    nearest.line.dist = dist;
                    nearest.line.p1 = p1;
                    nearest.line.p2 = p;
                    nearest.line.idx = i;
                    nearest.line.onLine.x = v3.x;
                    nearest.line.onLine.y = v3.y;
                }
            }
        }
        p1 = p;
        i ++;
    }
    if (nearest.point.idx > -1 && nearest.point.dist / 2 <= nearest.line.dist) {        
        nearest.active = nearest.point;
        nearest.near = true;
    } else if (nearest.line.idx > -1) {
        nearest.active = nearest.line;
        nearest.near = true;
    }
}
function drawLine(p1, p2) {
    ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
}
function drawLineArrow(p1, p2) {
    var nx = p1.x - p2.x;
    var ny = p1.y - p2.y;
    const d =( nx * nx + ny * ny) ** 0.5;
    if(d > arrowSize) {
        nx /= d;
        ny /= d;
        ctx.setTransform(-nx, -ny, ny, -nx, p2.x, p2.y);
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle;
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(-arrowSize, arrowSize / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(-arrowSize, -arrowSize / 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }
}
function drawPoint(p, size = pointSize) {
    ctx.rect(p.x - size / 2, p.y - size / 2, size, size);
}
function drawLines(points) {
    var p1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = lineStyle;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.beginPath()
    for(const p of points) {
        if (p1) { drawLine(p1 ,p) }
        p1 = p;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    if(points.length > 1) {
        drawLineArrow(points[points.length - 2], p1);
    }
}
function drawPoints(points) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = pointStyle;
    ctx.lineWidth = pointLineWidth;
    ctx.beginPath()
    for(const p of points) { drawPoint(p) }
    ctx.stroke();
}
function sizeCanvas() { 
    if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
        cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
        ctx.bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
}
const nearest = {
    point: { isPoint: true },
    line: { onLine: P2() },
    reset(minDist) {
        nearest.point.dist = minDist;
        nearest.point.idx = -1;
        nearest.line.dist = minDist;
        nearest.line.idx = -1;
        nearest.active = null;
        nearest.near = false;
    },
    draw() {
        const a = nearest.active;
        if (a) {
            if (a.isPoint) {
                ctx.strokeStyle = nearPointStyle;
                ctx.lineWidth = nearPointLineWidth;
                ctx.beginPath()
                drawPoint(a.p, nearPointSize);
                ctx.stroke();           
            } else {
                ctx.strokeStyle = nearLineStyle;
                ctx.lineWidth = nearLineWidth;
                ctx.beginPath()
                drawLine(a.p1, a.p2);
                ctx.stroke();       
                ctx.strokeStyle = nearPointStyle;
                ctx.lineWidth = nearPointLineWidth;
                ctx.beginPath()
                drawPoint(a.onLine, nearPointSize);
                ctx.stroke();   
            }
        }
    }           
}
function update() {
    cursor = "crosshair";
    toolTip = "";
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // отмена трансформации
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    sizeCanvas();
    ctx.fillStyle = checkerboard;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    if (!drag.dragging) { 
        nearestPointLine(points, mouse, MIN_SELECT_DIST);
        if (nearest.near && nearest.active.isPoint) { cursor = "move"; toolTip = "Drag to move point"}
        else if (nearest.near) { cursor = "crosshair"; toolTip = "Click/drag to cut and drag new point"  }
        else { 
            if (points.length < 2) {
                cursor = "crosshair"; 
                toolTip ="Click to add point";
             } else {
                cursor = "default"; 
                toolTip = "";
             }
         }
    }
    drawLines(points);
    drawPoints(points);
    nearest.draw();
    if((mouse.button & 1) === 1) {
        if (!drag.dragging) {
            if(points.length < 2 && !nearest.near) {
                points.push(P2(mouse.x, mouse.y));
                mouse.button = 0;
            } else if (nearest.near) {
                if (nearest.active.isPoint) {
                    drag.point = nearest.active.p;
                } else {
                    drag.point = P2(nearest.active.onLine.x, nearest.active.onLine.y);
                    points.splice(nearest.active.idx, 0, drag.point);
                    nearestPointLine(points, drag.point, 20);
                }
                drag.offX = drag.point.x - mouse.x;
                drag.offY = drag.point.y - mouse.y;
                drag.dragging = true;
            }
        }
        if(drag.dragging) {
            drag.point.x = drag.offX + mouse.x;
            drag.point.y = drag.offY + mouse.y;
            drag.point.x = drag.point.x < 1 ? 1 : drag.point.x > w - 2 ? w - 2 : drag.point.x;
            drag.point.y = drag.point.y < 1 ? 1 : drag.point.y > h - 2 ? h - 2 : drag.point.y;
            cursor = "none";
        }
    } else if((mouse.button & 1) === 0) {
        drag.dragging = false;
        drag.point = null;
    }
    canvas.title = toolTip;
    canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [arrow with modification point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366465/7394871) от участника  [@Blindman67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877726/blindman67).</sub>